# Change logging level for Bokeh serve

Tags: logging, plot, bokeh

*Note from maintainers: This question concerns the obsolete first generation Bokeh server. For details about modern Bokeh server applications, see:*

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html

---

---

***OBSOLETE:***

I am using the following command to host a plotting page on my server:

```
bokeh serve <script.py>
```

This all works fine, but the logging level is much to precise. I would like to change the logging level in such a way that it only shows errors. Yet, when run

```
bokeh serve -h
```

and look at the help provided, there is no option to do so. Is there a way to change the logging level in another way?

Answer (score 2):

Bokeh has several different log levels.  On the terminal session you're using...try:

```
export BOKEH_LOG_LEVEL=error
```